# Can I make a http request from smart contract code?

Tags: smart-contract, eosio.cdt, c++, eosio-cpp, http

I know that eosio has http plugins, which is why I'm thinking that maybe a http library is embedded to the eosio.hpp and that I can use it internally to send http requests. Is this possible?

My goal is simply to notify an external server whenever my multi_index table is updated. Therefore, I need to make a post request within the smart contract. Is this possible without including external http libraries? and if not, how can I include and link to the library using the eosio-cpp command line tool?

Comment: Hello you can use the DAPP Network oracles to do this, but other than that base layer EOSIO does not provide this feature. https://liquidapps.gitbook.io/liquidapps-documentation/dapp-network-services/dapp-network-services/liquidharmony/creating-an-oracle-request-uri

Answer (score 1):

It turns out we can't, because HTTP is not deterministic. Check this [discussion](https://github.com/EOSIO/eosio.cdt/issues/1234#issuecomment-964013704).